# Tiktok oAuth2 return 10013 error_code, when exchange code with access_token

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, oauth, axios

I want to use TikTok API with oAuth mechanism.

And my controller for start oAuth Mechanism Like that:

```
    logger.info('Handle request from Tiktok Auth')

    const csrfState = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)
    res.cookie('csrfState', csrfState, { maxAge: 60000 })

    let url = 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect/'

    url += `?client_key=${process.env.TIKTOK_CLIENT_KEY}`
    url += '&scope=user.info.basic,video.list'
    url += '&response_type=code'
    url += '&redirect_uri=https://www.helloworld.com/tiktok/callback/'
    url += `&state=${csrfState}`

    res.redirect(url)
```

And my callback code snipped like that:

```
const config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/access_token/',
      params: {
        client_key: process.env.TIKTOK_CLIENT_KEY,
        client_secret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code,
      },
      headers: {},
    }
    return axios(config)
```

But, as a response I received this response with status:200 :

```
{
    "data": {
        "captcha": "",
        "desc_url": "",
        "description": "",
        "error_code": 10013
    },
    "message": "error"
}
```

I researched status codes for TikTok API, but I cannot find anything.
What does the "10013" error code mean?
Why I'm getting this error? How can I solve this?
Please Help!

Comment: Wrong tiktok secret?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the TikTok Error Codes here.

https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/getting-started-android-handling-errors/

**Error 10013: Client key or client secret error.**